# Why is my CNN returning tokens instead or readable labels?

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision, resnet, fast-ai

I am currently studying machine learning and have created a CNN using fastai that labels the category of clothes items. I built this model using the Fashion-MNIST data set.
Everything funcitons fine and it looks like it's predicting correctly but I dont know how to make it return the labels and categories rather than this weird tokenized text it is returning. where am I going wrong?
Here is some code

This is where I create the dataframe that has the category mapped to the image path.

```
from fastcore.all import *
ds = dataFrame.filter(['masterCategory', 'imagePath'], axis=1)
ds

masterCategory  imagePath
0   Apparel ../input/fashion-product-images-small/images/1...
1   Apparel ../input/fashion-product-images-small/images/3...
2   Accessories ../input/fashion-product-images-small/images/5...
3   Apparel ../input/fashion-product-images-small/images/2...
4   Apparel ../input/fashion-product-images-small/images/5...
... ... ...
44419   Footwear    ../input/fashion-product-images-small/images/1...
44420   Footwear    ../input/fashion-product-images-small/images/6...
44421   Apparel ../input/fashion-product-images-small/images/1...
44422   Personal Care   ../input/fashion-product-images-small/images/4...
44423   Accessories ../input/fashion-product-images-small/images/5...
44424 rows × 2 columns
```

Then I create a datablock

```
def getImages(d): return d['imagePath']
def getLabel(d): return d['masterCategory']
from fastai.vision.all import *
dblock = DataBlock(
    blocks=(ImageBlock, MultiCategoryBlock), 
    get_x=getImages,
    splitter=RandomSplitter(valid_pct=0.2, seed=42),
    get_y=getLabel,
    item_tfms=[Resize(192, method='squish')]
)
```

Then I use the dataloader and when I show batch, but I get these weird labels instead of the the mater categories.

```
dsets = dblock.dataloaders(ds, bs=32)
    
dsets.show_batch(max_n=20)
```

[image: products with non human readable labels(I need them to be normal lables)]

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, The block I needed is not MultiCategoryBlock, it is CategoryBlock. I thought since there where multiple categories ot pick from that is what was needed but no MulticategoryBlock is used to label one image with multiple categories. Not to pick from multiple categories.